# Animation with jquery , animate / toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would like to toggle `#header-connect-content-toggled` with a `onclick` on `#header-connect-content-avatar`, i tried two solutions:

- 1 : http://jsfiddle.net/DRhw6/19/

  ```
  $("#header-connect-content-avatar").click(function() {
    $("#header-connect-content-toggled").animate({width:'toggle'},2000);
  });
  ```
- 2 : http://jsfiddle.net/DRhw6/20/

  ```
  $("#header-connect-content-avatar").click(function() {
    $("#header-connect-content-toggled").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 2000); 
  });
  ```

I have a div with fix content and another div with width variable.

Problem is , the content is verticaly modified or the container div does not follow the movement...

what is the correct way for this animation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/yinkadet/DRhw6/28/ , I'm guessing that's what you want. The first approach is cleaner, I just added an overflow-x:hidden and made it not wrap on whitespace as below:

```
 <div id="header-connect-content-toggled" style="float: left; background-color: #800000; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;">
```

That way, it slides right without the content breaking into new lines and stretching out your divs.

I hope this helps